# Cipher Ciphe Ciph

Tags: cipher

"*What is this?*", he asked himself.

Looking at the paper, it read "*Amw ytc xffu tx honzarz vmghers.*"

He then turned the paper the other way, and found this:

> *Cipher.* | **A** | ***The first letter.***
>
> *You wish to find it.* | **piece** | ***The last letter too, is that better?***
>
> *Ciphe.* | **of** | ***The middle letter of newsletter,***
>
> *You wish to find i.* | **useless** | ***The set (i.e two obvious words) of words in pacesetter.***
>
> *Ciph.* | **text** | ***Do that***
>
> *You wish to find.* | **?** | ***And you're done!***

Can you help him?

Comment: What is the set of words in pacesetter?? Pacesetter has like 50 odd words in it...

Comment: @Sid "Pacesetter" is made up of a very clear set of words. Don't look around for every single word you can make using this combination of letters.

Comment: Pacesetter may be Secret Tape.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar What secret tape?

Comment: @TheBitByte: In the right track ?

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar You mean whether you're on the right track? That I can't tell you unless I know your line of reasoning.

Comment: @TheBitByte: As you have ("he" in the story) solved the cipher, am I going through the right thought process to solve it, by breaking pacesetter in secret tape ? That's what I meant by right track.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

> `You are good at solving ciphers`

Explanation:

> The cipher used is a Vigenere cipher with the key `cycycyrrrrtepacesetteraaaa`.
> How to build the key:
> 1) Clue #1: *"The first letter."* - Add every first letter of each line, i.e. `cycycy`
> 2) Clue #2: *"The last letter."* - Add every last letter of each line, i.e. `rrrrte`
> 3) Clue #4: *"The set (i.e two obvious words) of words in pacesetter."*. - Just add `pacesetter`
> 4) Clue #5: *"Do that and you're done"* - This indicates that the remaining letters of the ciphertext (`hers`) don't have to be encrypted anymore, so add `aaaa` to the key.
> Bonus: Clue #3 *"The middle letter of newsletter,"* is a red herring, since it doesn't have a middle letter.

Comment: Well done, congrats!

Comment: @TheBitByte Thanks! Now I only hope I can also solve [The Cipher Machine](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42960/the-cipher-machine) :P It's definitely the hardest cipher of yours so far (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

I will add some thoughts here and see if they are on the right track and someone can workout something with them:

First of all

> Text in brackets ||, can be arranged like: A piece of useless text?

Then in Ciphe line

> As Ciphe is not complete it could give us a hint, since we are removing the last r like Cipher --> Ciphe, then newsletter --> newslette where l is the middle letter.

Then in You wish to find i.

> Pacesetter can be split up in pace and setter as @TheBitByte pointed out.

Probably all what I stated could be wrong or people already deduce it, but somewhat I want to solve this

Comment: You got misled by a false clue. Which one it is, you'll have to find out.

Comment: Ah that sounds better!

Comment: It gave me more information (and spirit to continue looking for the key clue), I'll keep thinking about this!

Comment: Oh, okay, now I see. Keep going!